# return key from hash with more values

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash

```
{"june"=>["sarah"], "sarah"=>["tom", "simon"], "tom"=>["claudiu"]}
```

and I need a way to return the key with most values on his array. Any suggestion or help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value can always responds to a `size` message

```
h.max_by { |key, value| value.size }
 => ["sarah", ["tom", "simon"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max_by` method:

```
a = {"june"=>["sarah"], "sarah"=>["tom", "simon"], "tom"=>["claudiu"]}
a.max_by { |d| d[1].count }[0]
#=> "sarah"
```